# How to put one picture on two screens in fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I have a project using fullpage.js. And I absolutely do not know how to put one big picture on two screens, so that it does not remain fixed.

Comment: you can add background images using css .what is the issue ?http://jsfiddle.net/nppyyqax/38/

Comment: I need one main picture to two sections, not two same pictures for two sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut the big picture in half and save it as two pictures.

Set the first half as `background-image` of first section and second one as `background-image` of last section. You also need to change the `background-position` to `100% 50%` for first and `0 50%` for second.

In short:

```
.first-half {
  background: url('/path/to/top-half.png') bottom center no-repeat /cover;
}
.second-half {
  background: url('/path/to/bottom-half.png') top center no-repeat /cover;
}
```

See [background shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) for details.

Here's an example:

```js
var slideTimeout;

$('#fullpage').fullpage({});
```

```css
#section1{
    background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKI2k.jpg") bottom center /cover;
}
#section2{
  background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXODm.jpg") top center /cover;
}
#fullpage {
  color: white;
}
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.65);
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header id="header">

</header>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section1">
      <div class="centered">
        First Section
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
      <div class="centered">
        Second Section
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```